# SFTP with ChrootDirectory option and still allow user to create/modify directories under home

Tags: sftp

Currently I have an SFTP setup so that user can SFTP into their home and upload files to the directories already created by root. Example and SSH config below:

```
/home
/home/azhao/
/home/azhao/public_html
```

`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
Match Group www-data
    ChrootDirectory %h
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    PermitTunnel no
    X11Forwarding no
```

User `azhao` can upload files and create directories within `/public_html`, but **cannot** create and upload files under `/home/azhao`.

With `ChrootDirectory` option, I understand that `/home/azhao` is owned by root. Is there a way to work around this limitation or a way **not** to force home directories to be owned by root and still allow SFTP to work?

Answer (score 1):

The only option is to use /home as the ChrooDirectory and make sure that other user-directories use 0700 and/or use ACL for further security.